# Buffer I/O error on /dev/sda2, running fsck.hfsplus returns OK

Tags: raspberry-pi, io, dmesg, ubuntu-mate

At the moment, I'm mounting a USB hard drive running HFS+ on a Raspberry Pi 3 at boot to be writable. Not 100% sure what I did, but the drive is suddenly throwing up errors such as `Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 18266273, async page read` while I'm trying to stream via Plex.

Following up on the suggestion from `dmesg` I installed and ran `fsck.hfsplus`, but `fsck` is simply returning `The volume Tom's Disk appears to be OK.` every time. I've also run it through First Aid on Disk Utility on my Mac, and got similar results.

I'm kind of at a loss because the drive seems to be fine, but I can't stop `Filesystem was not cleanly unmounted, running fsck.hfsplus is recommended.  mounting read-only.` messages. Is there any way of telling Ubuntu that the drive is fine? Seems to be the only reason why Plex won't play my media right now...

Answer (score 0):

The first message is the kernel telling that there is a hardware failure and you should belief those warnings without any doubt to be honest. Most likely the drive has gone thru it hot spare area already and can't really recover from the failures it is having. Most video formats can handle data loss as it will drop a couple of frames or will have a bad display for a few seconds so you won't really notice it. You can run the ***dd*** command on the device to see if you can trigger the event again, but wiser it would be to run ***smartctl*** and do a full scan of the disk. After the scan you can query the health of the device and then most likely decommission the disk.

Keep in mind that both the tool fsck.hfsplus as HFS+ are having limitations. fsck.hfsplus can't fix all issues for example and HFS+ has design flaws concerning data integrity as it will not detect disk and/or metadata failure correctly. For the later Apple originally was looking to take a license on Sun Microsystems ZFS solution, but after the Oracle takeover developed Apple File System (APFS) to resolve issues with HFS+.

Comment: I ran `smartctl` last night and got back that the drive was healthy. I'm getting ready to decommission the drive, regardless. I've seen enough posts relating to this problem and suggesting damaged drives to get the gist... It's a shame really, but it is an old-ish drive now. Replacing in a week. Cheers for the answer.